# Migration of Metabots from Automation Anywhere Version 11 to A360

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

How does migration of metabots work in A360? Since the feature of metabot is not supported in the latest version of A360, what are the post migration steps we need to take while migrating them.
Metabots have two components - a) DLLs/Logics b) Record screen. Can someone explain how to successfully handle the migration of these commands to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

The migration tool merges them within the migrated bot.  Words of advice....start manually rebuilding these.  The migration is ugly and at times confusing to understand what the migration did.

Could rebuild the metabots as sub tasks/bots if they are used in many other bots.

Comment: Agreed. Rebuild the bots. The migration tool is only good for simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

When migrating the metabot from v11 to the A360 platform, sub-bots are created for every function\logic used in the DLL(metabot). You can find these sub-bots in the Metabots folder on A360 Control Room.